# JavaScript scope: referencing parent object member from child member's closure

Tags: javascript, scope

Newbie to JavaScript here.

How do I reference member `foo` from within member `foobar`, given that `foobar`'s in a closure?

```
var priv = {

    foo: "bar",

    foobar: (function() {
        return this.foo === "bar";
    })()

};
```

The code above fails. In it, `this.foo` is `undefined`. If I change `this.foo` to `priv.foo`, it's still `undefined`. How do I reference `priv.foo` from within the `foobar` closure?

Comment: do you really want to call your closure? I'd try to remove `()` after `})`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do. `foobar` is actually a few dozen lines. :/

Comment: I explained in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to read any properties of an object in its defination during its initialization since `prev` will be undefined at that time.
When you're trying to call a clojure inside it, it refers to undefined `this` or `priv`.

Probably you wanted to write:

```
foobar: (function() {
    return this.foo === "bar";
})
```

without `()` in the end. And then you could call it as `priv.foobar();`

If you still need to call it, you could define `foobar` after `foo`:

```
var priv = {
    foo: "bar"
};

priv.foobar = (function() {
    return priv.foo === "bar";
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't defining a closure - I don't think that there is any way to access `foo` from your function as `priv` is not yet initialised.

What exactly are you trying to do?  The following is equivalent to what I understand your sample is trying to do, but my guess is that I'm not understanding the problem:

```
// Set elsewhere
var foo = "bar";

var priv = {
    foo: foo ,
    foobar: foo == "bar"
};
```

Comment: In summary, I have a giant JS file. It defines some private variables and a public object. I'm trying to encapsulate these private variables into one object, but each private variable except for one depends on another private variable's value. So instead, assume `foobar` is a run-time, dynamic calculation based off of the value of `foo`. Make sense?